# .otf won't render properly in some browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I downloaded [this font](http://www.dafont.com/es/surface.font)

And this is how I include it into my stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "surface";
    src: url(fonts/Surface-Medium.otf);
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
#site-header .site-logo a {
  color: #00B1ED;
  font-family: "surface";
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
#site-header .site-logo a span {
    color: white;

}
#site-header .site-logo a span:last-child {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

the problem is that in google chrome it renders really bad:

[image]

but in firefox it works well:
[image]

Am I Doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that I was including the normal style font and then implementing the bold,

For some reason it was working in firefox so it make sense it failed on others, but this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "surface";
    src: url(fonts/Surface-Medium.otf);
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "surface";
    src: url(fonts/Surface_Bold.otf);
    font-style: bold;
}
```

Made it work in other browsers too

Of corse, the bold.otf file must be included in the used path

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows browsers will only render *TrueType* fonts with any degree of smoothness. OpenType (CFF) generally will not render well with the Windows rendering engine. Not only that but these TrueType fonts must contain hinting data that tells Windows how to place pixels at small sizes. Consider running your OTF through the Font Squirrel Generator to give you all the font formats needed along with the correct CSS code.

Comment: Hi there, I don't know what Do you mean... i tried downloading it from here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Surface?q=SURFACE but the link is broken... any idea?

Comment: Link is fixed, but unrelated to what you are trying to do. You must convert your font from an OTF to a TTF with hinting. Go here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

convert the font to embedded Open Type(.eot) and also add .woff for other browser support.
It renders properly in browsers.

Or try this for chrome `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`